# C++ Linux: Declaring an array in a class causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault

I have a class, and when I try to add the following declaration in the header file:

```
bool m_DeviceIDs[100];
```

I get a segmentation fault.
Any ideas why?
The entire class header:

```
class Protocol
{
    vector<ProtocolDevice*> _DeviceProtocols;
    vector<Device>* _Devices;
    Helper _Helper;
    vector <unsigned char> m_MessageToSend;//xml messages to send
    bool m_LockDevices;
    //bool m_DeviceIDs[100];
    unsigned int GetVacantID();
public:
    Protocol(void){};
    Protocol(vector<Device>* devices);
    ~Protocol(void);
    void RemoveDevice(int DeviceID);
    void AddDevice(Device device);
    bool SendPing( int DeviceID);
    bool GetInputStatus( int DeviceID);
    void GetLowLevelConfiguration(int DeviceID);
    bool ActivateOutput(char outputID, bool state, int DeviceID);
    bool ActivateBSUHF(unsigned char state, int DeviceID);
    bool ActivateUnitLF(unsigned char state,int DeviceID);
    void StartDeviceListeners();
    void WriteMessageToDevice(int DeviceID, unsigned char* message, int length);
    vector<unsigned char> CollectDataFromDevice(int DeviceID,int dataLength);
    int GetDeviceAvailableDataLength(int DeviceID);
    void RefreshServerDetails(int DeviceID, string host, int port,int reconnectInterval);
    void ReconnectHost(int DeviceID);
    void SendVersion(int,bool);
    void StartListentoDevice(int DeviceID);
    void StopListenToDevice(int DeviceID);
    bool SendSetLowLevelConfiguration(LowLevelConfiguration llConfig, int WaitAckMS,     bool FromBaseToLocator,int DeviceID);
    bool OperateExciterRead(char operation, unsigned int ReaderID, int Retries,int DeviceID);
    bool RequestConfigurationFromLocator(int ReaderID,int TimeOut, int Retries,int DeviceID);
    void SendXMLMessage(unsigned char opcode,   vector<unsigned char> XMLData,unsigned int MessageID, unsigned int SourceID, unsigned int DestID);
    void Mute(int Length, int DeviceID);
};
```

Comment: Should `vector<Device>* _Devices;` be a `vector<Device*> _Devices;` -- not a pointer to vector, but vector of pointers like the `_DeviceProtocols`?

Comment: It's not the declaration that causes the crash, it's how you use the declared variable. Compile your program with debug information (use the `-g` flag when compiling) and run in a debugger to see where the crash happens.

Comment: Should `m_DeviceIDs` be an array of `int`s instead of `bool`s?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: It is the declaration. For debug purposes I left the declaration but removed the usage of the declared variable but I still got the segmentation fault. Only when I remove the declaration I don't get the error.

Comment: Try moving the m_Devices declaration to the top of the class. Does the segfault disappear? Then the segfault is probably not be caused by it.. It is a side-effect of a mistake you made somewhere else in your code, which manifests itself on adding m_DeviceIDs to the bottom. My money is on some illegal memory access like Out-of-bounds array access.

Comment: @blackbird: No - it should be indeed an array of bool

Comment: Also use tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find memory problems.

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell where the issue is without seeing how do you use given class (bad memory managment, race conditions, etc), maybe you can prepare some litle example or given more context?

Comment: Your problem isn't in the code you showed.

Comment: Show some code where the segmentation fault actually occurs.

Comment: Is it possible that there's code using the class that doesn't get rebuilt when you modify the header? Are your makefiles (or whatever build scripts you're using) correct?

Comment: @Apokal: I'm using this class in thousands of places across the program. I declare it inside a singleton class called Som.cpp:       _Protocol = Protocol(&m_pDevices); an example for a usage of it:Som::Instance()->GetProtocol().StopListenToDevice(1);

Comment: Your code has bugs. The addition of the array exposes the bugs in the form of a segfault. You'll need to find the root cause. Since you have a pointer member and post an assignment as an example, but apparently haven't implemented the assignment operator or copy constructor, you should start by implementing them.

Comment: @user1997268, ok, got it, then my only suggestion is to "play" with `m_DeviceIDs` types, try `int` or `vector<bool>`

Comment: Maybe it happens when you use it. In debug mode boolean values are usually initialized to false, while in release mode to true (because they are not initialized and memory is usually different than zero). Make sure to initialize your array in consistent manner before use it.

Comment: modifying the m_DeviceIDs to std::bitset<100> as suggested in the answer below solved the issue - but I still wonder why it doesn't work with booleans...

Comment: See the comment from @Jepessen, and remember that uninitialized data (like an uninitialized array) contains indeterminate values. Using uninitialized data leads to undefined behavior. And a debugger normally clears (i.e. initializes) data which is why some things might work when running in a debugger.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: As I mentioned before, I tried it without using it a t all (for debugging purposes)!

Comment: Then you need to use Valgrind or a debugger to help you find the cause of the error. You are doing something weird somewhere in the code you're not showing us, and it's not the actual member variable declaration. Are you declaring an array of this class anywhere, and it's to big for the stack with the member? Also enable more warnings when compiling, as warnings are often an indicator of undefined behavior fixing them might fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem in the code you've shown, but you might want to try a [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) instead of a `bool` array as it's more versitile and space effiecent, something like:

```
#include <bitset>
std::bitset<100> m_DeviceIDs;
```

Comment: Indeed it works with bitset. I still wonder why it doesn't work with boolean...